# Allowing JavaScript closure to inherit variables from the parent's scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, anonymous-function

I am able to pass a variable from the parents scope to an anonymous function as follows:

```
var f = function(myVar) {
    alert(myVar);
}
f('hello');
```

I don't wish to do so, but instead allow the closure to directly access the parent's scope.

PHP allows me to do so as described by http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php.  For instance, by using `use ($message)`, the parent's `$message` variable is available in the closure.

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such
>   variables must be passed to the use language construct. ...
>
> Example #3 Inheriting variables from the parent scope
>
> ```
> // Inherit $message
> $example = function () use ($message) {
>     var_dump($message);
> };
> $example();
> ```

How can this be performed using JavaScript?

The specific parts I am struggling with are this part of the below script.

```
select: function(e, ui) {
    //...
    if (typeof options.autocomplete.select !== "undefined"){
        options.autocomplete.select();
    }
}

select: function() {
    //How can I access editable, elem, and ui.  It shows each as being undefined yet I can access it in the parents scope
}
```

When executing the script, it shows them as undefined, yet I see they are defined by my `console.log` in the parent scope.

Furthermore, if I explicitly pass them using `options.autocomplete.select(editable, ui, elem);`, I can access them.

full script:

```
xWrap(dialog.find('a.car'),'autocomplete',chartsId, {name:'carId', title:'Car Name', autocomplete: {
    url: "/1.0/cars",
    params: {term:null, fields:['id','name']},
    select: function(editable, elem, ui) {
        console.log('chart-list select','editable',editable,'elem',elem,'this',this,'ui', ui)
        var $td=$(elem).parent()
        var series = $td.closest('table').find('th').eq($td.index()).data('id');
        var category=$td.parent().data('id');
        editable.option('params', {'carId': ui.item.id});
        editable.option('url', '/1.0/cars/'+carId+'/'+series+'/'+category)
    }
}});

$.fn.xEdit = function(type, options) {
    //console.log('xEdit',this,type, options);
    function chk(o, a) {
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (typeof o[a[i]] === "undefined"){
                $.error('Property "' +  a[i] + '" must be provided to jQuery.xEdit');
            }
        }
    }
    var common={
        placement: 'right',
        ajaxOptions: {type: "PUT"},
        send: 'always'
        // pk: null, title: null, params: {name: null}, url: null, //Must be passed
    }
    if (typeof options.name === "undefined"){
        $.error('Property "name" must be provided to jQuery.xEdit');
    }
    options.params={name: options.name};
    delete(options.name);
    switch(type) {
        case 'text':
            options.type='text';
            chk(options,['pk','title','url']);
            this.editable($.extend({}, common, options));
            break;
        case 'select':
            options.type='select';
            chk(options,['pk','title','url', 'source']);
            this.editable($.extend({}, common, {value: null}, options));
            break;
        case 'autocomplete':
            options.type='text';
            chk(options,['pk','title','url','autocomplete']);
            chk(options.autocomplete,['url','params']);
            this.editable($.extend({}, common, {value: null}, options))
            .on('shown', function(e, editable) {
                //console.log('on.show','this',this,'e',e,'editable',editable)
                var elem=this;    //Needed only for rare case 
                var $input=editable.input.$input.val('');
                var $button=$input.parent().next().find('button.editable-submit').css('opacity', 0.3)
                .bind('click.prevent', function() {return false;});
                $input.focus(function() {
                    $button.css('opacity', 0.3).bind('click.prevent', function() {return false;});
                })
                .autocomplete({
                    source: function( request, response ) { //get All Points
                        options.autocomplete.params.term=request.term;
                        $.getJSON( options.autocomplete.url, options.autocomplete.params, function(json) {
                            var data=[];
                            for (var j = 0; j < json.length; j++) {
                                data.push({id:json[j].id,label:json[j].name});
                            }
                            response(data);
                        } );
                    },
                    minLength: 2,
                    position: { my : "left top+20", at: "left bottom" },
                    select: function(e, ui) {
                        console.log('xEdit select','editable',editable,'elem',elem,'this',this,'ui', ui, 'options', options)
                        $input.blur();
                        $button.css('opacity', 1).unbind('click.prevent');
                        if (typeof options.autocomplete.select !== "undefined"){
                            options.autocomplete.select(editable, elem, ui,);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .autocomplete('widget').click(function() {return false;});
            });
            break;
        default: $.error('Type "' +  type + '" is not available for jQuery.xEdit');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Global variable**

```js
var myVar = "hello";
function f () {
   console.log(myVar);
}

function myMainFn() {
  f();
}

myMainFn();
```

**Using arrow functions**

```js
var f = () => {
   console.log(this.myVar);
}

function myMainFn() {
  // The arrow function above has access to window's context
  window.myVar = "hello";
  f();
}

myMainFn();
```

**Binding the `this` context**

```js
function f () {
   console.log(this.myVar);
}

function myMainFn() {
  this.myVar = "hello";
  f.bind(this)();
}

myMainFn();
```

**Use an object to hold the variable**

The closure will be made on the object, but modifications to internal elements will be visible.

```js
function f () {
  var myObj = { myVar: "hello" }

  function myMainFn() {
    f();
  }

  myMainFn();
  console.log(myObj.myVar);
}
```

According to your code, an alternative would be bind the `this` context and set those attributes:

```
select: function(e, ui) {
    //...
    if (typeof options.autocomplete.select !== "undefined") {
        this.editable = editable;
        this.elem = elem;
        this.ui = ui;
                                          +--- Bind with the current context 'this'
                                          |
                                          v
        options.autocomplete.select.bind(this)();
    }
}

select: function() {
    //How can I access editable, elem, and ui.  It shows each as being undefined yet I can access it in the parents scope
    console.log(this.editable);
    console.log(this.elem);
    console.log(this.ui);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ele,  I've never heard of the arrow context before.  Is it applicable to the actual new script I just posted?

Comment: @user1032531 no, however see my updated answer with an alternative.

Comment: Thanks again Ele.  This would still require me to set in stone what will be available to the closure function, true?  My reason why I did not wish to explicitly pass them is to allow flexibility should I later need something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can already access variables from the enclosing scope:

```js
let foo = 3;

function bar() {
  console.log(foo);
}

bar();
```

Comment: My bad.  I did not state that `foo` and `bar()` were not defined in the same scope.  Maybe it doesn't matter?  I thought I was observing that it did.  I better do some more testing.

Comment: I tested again, but still cannot access the variables.  I just posted the actual script which I am having problems with.  Why can't I access them, yet you surely showed that I should be able to?

Comment: @user1032531 That `console.log` you did starting with "'xEdit select'" prints `undefined` for all variables? Did you try logging them on different locations? As far as scopes go, they should definitely refer to the variables declared earlier.

Comment: When I execute it, `select: function(e, ui) { console.log('xEdit select','editable',editable,'elem',elem,'this',this,'ui', ui, 'options', options)` definitely shows results, so I don't know what is different.